# Invertible matrix and inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Establish if the matrix $A\in M_3 (\Bbb{Z}_9)$

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 3 & 0 \\
    0 & 3 & 6
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

is invertible, and if so, find the inverse matrix.

Comment: Do you know how to do it if we were working in $M_3(\Bbb R)$ instead?  Do you know which if any of those methods work for $M_3(\Bbb Z_9)$?

Comment: Show at least some effort and don't just post your problems to be solved by community. You haven't even asked any question.

Answer (score 3):

Since [hint should be posted as answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10597/290189), I post my hints here.

> 1. Add the second column to the third column.  The bottom right corner vanishes.
> 2. To calculate $\det(A) \pmod 9$, expand along the last line.  What's the cofactor matrix at the $(3,2)$-th entry?
> 3. Verifty that the determinant of the minor matrix $\det(M_{32}) \not\equiv 0 \pmod 3$, so $\det(A) \not\equiv 0 \pmod 9$